# How do you format a sentence to avoid or use "to to" correctly?

Tags: prepositions, word-order, writing-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rules about prepositions and duplicating 'to'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7274/rules-about-prepositions-and-duplicating-to)

> Where did you travel to to get that?

Using to, to has always looked/seemed awkward to me. What is the proper way to express this?

Comment: If you choose to rewrite, a small alteration you might try would be to take one of the suggestions in the related question, such as *To where did you travel to get that?* or inserting something between the two *tos*, as in *Where did you travel to, in order to get that?*

Comment: This question about "to to" is too interesting for me too.

Comment: @aedia λ, you are correct. This is a duplicate question to the question linked in your comment. I did not find it before asking. Thank you for directing me to the correct place. If you'd like to post your second comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: see the duplicate question. the first _to_ is part of the verb 'travel', the second goes with 'get'

Answer (score 0):

*to* again is superfluous. Use:

> Where did you travel to get that?

Comment: This seems a scanty answer.