# Using had twice

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, past-perfect, repetition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “had had” mean? How does this differ from “had”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2658/what-does-had-had-mean-how-does-this-differ-from-had)

Is this correct usage?

I had had enough food?

Comment: Possible dupe of [What does “had had” mean? How does this differ from “had”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2658/what-does-had-had-mean-how-does-this-differ-from-had/2698#2698)

Comment: See [James while John had had had had had had had had had had had a better effect on the teacher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_while_John_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_a_better_effect_on_the_teacher)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's correct; it uses the [past perfect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Past_tense) tense.

**Edit**: you can find a better answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2658/what-does-had-had-mean-how-does-this-differ-from-had/2698#2698) (and this question is actually a duplicate of that one).

Comment: You might enjoy this absurd example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_while_John_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_a_better_effect_on_the_teacher