# A question regarding "had" vs "had had"

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, simple-past-vs-past-perfect, simple-past-as-past-participle

Which one you would choose?

> I really had had a pleasant meal until you came
>   OR
>   I really had a pleasant meal until you came

I personally think that both are correct, but I am interested to see which one has greater emphasis.

Comment: "I was having a pleasant meal until you came" would be better IMO

Comment: related: [using had had in a sentence ](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84578/using-had-had-in-a-sentence)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is when you are talking about and when you are talking.

I am having a pleasant meal but now you are here. - Present

Yesterday I had a pleasant meal until you came. - Past

Yesterday when you came I told you I had had a pleasant meal until you came. - Past Perfect