# When do we use “had had” and “have had”?

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-perfect, auxiliary-verbs, simple-past-vs-past-perfect

I have seen several sentences in English where some writers have written *had* twice in a row. I am a bit confused about when the grammar calls for using *had had*.

For example:

> - I **had had** my car for four years before I ever learned to drive it.
> - I **had had** a bath, but I didn't feel clean, so I had a shower.

Comment: I want to know the general rule where used 'had had', 'have had'.

Comment: Kutubu, you might be interested in our new proposal designed specifically for those who want to learn the English language: English Language Learners (ell.stackexchange.com). On EL&U this kind of questions are considered at best too basic, but on ELL they are welcome. Please, take a look now or, at any rate, be aware that that proposal exists. And please, don't use "grammer", it is incorrect! Thank you.

Comment: This question has actually been asked, and answered, many times before. Please search the site before posting. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

There's no special magic with "*had had*",  they don't really go together as a pair anymore than "*had wanted*" go together.

So don't worry so much about how to use "*had had*" as a unit of grammar, they will come together naturally when you want to express the verb '*to have*' in the past perfect.

Let's consider a different verb for a moment like "*to want*".  Suppose that at sometime in the past I wanted to do something, but I don't want to do it at present.  You might say, "Last year I *had wanted* to buy a new television, but now I don't have the money."

Now let's use the verb *to have* instead of *to want*.  Suppose that at sometime in the past I had something, but I don't have it at present.  You might say, "Last year I *had had* the idea to buy a new television, but now I'm not sure I want to."

Comment: Jim, "Last year I **had wanted** to buy a new television, but now I don't have the money," sounds strange to my ear, if not incorrect. I think "Last year I **would have** wanted to buy a new television, but now I don't have the money," sounds better.

Comment: @Carlo_R.- Regardless of how it sounds to your ear, it is correct.  *Would have wanted* is a conditional.  If <some fact> had been true, I would have wanted <something>.

Comment: Why do you use <had wanted>? Should be better to replace it with <wanted> or <have wanted>..

Comment: Because that’s the construction I needed to make the point I was trying to make.  Would you have liked it better if I had said, “Last year I had wanted to buy a new television, but then I found out that if I were to wait until next year I could get a better one for less money.”?

Answer (score 9):

In most cases, `have` is used as an auxiliary verb. Examples of auxiliary verbs,

> I `have` to go to school.
>   I `need` to go to school.
>   They `have` eaten breakfast.
>   She `has` never played football.
>   He `does` not eat breakfast.

However, the verb `have` is also often used as a *proper* verb (as opposed to being an auxiliary verb) in place of *proper* verbs such as `eat` or `partake`.

> I am `eating` breakfast.
>   I have `eaten` breakfast.
>   She has never `indulged in` sex by the time of her 18th birthday, today.

can be translated to

> I am `having` breakfast.
>   I have `had` breakfast.
>   She has never `had` sex by the time of her 18th birthday, today.

Referring to a past time of reference,

> She had never `had` sex by the time of her 18th birthday, three years ago.
>   She had `had` sex by the time of her 18th birthday, three years ago.

Another mode of use is its auxiliary use to encapsulate a perfected/completed participation.
e.g., `have experience`,

> Do you paint houses?
>   Are you familiar with painting houses?
>   Do you {have experience} painting houses?
>
> I am hiring her because she does {have experience} painting houses.
>   I am hiring her because she has {had experience} painting houses.
>   I am hiring her because she has {fulfilled experience} painting houses.
>   I am hiring her because she has {had painted houses} before.
>
> I hired her because she did {have familiarity} programming in C#.
>   I hired her because she {fulfilled familiarity} programming in C#.
>   I had hired her because she had {had familiarity} programming in C#.
>   I had hired her because she had {acquired familiarity} programming in C#.

Then why not simply say,

> I had hired her because she had {familiarity} programming in C#.

What is the difference between saying

> Since he had {had the experience} of being kidnapped, he did not panic.
>   Since he had {gone thro the experience} of being kidnapped, he did not panic.

vs

> Since he had the experience of being kidnapped, he did not panic.

?

The difference is in the temporal displacement of the observation.

When you say

> Since he had the experience of being kidnapped, he did not panic.

You meant to say,

> When he was kidnapped in 1980, he did not panic because we know that today he had experience of being kidnapped before 1980.

When you say,

> Since he had {gone thro/had the experience} of being kidnapped, he did not panic.

You meant to say,

> When he was kidnapped in 1980, he did not panic because we know that in 1980 he had {had the experience} of being kidnapped before 1980.

Therefore the difference is in saying,

- we see that today, he had experience of being kidnapped before 1980.
- we see that in 1980, he had had experience of being kidnapped before 1980.

Both sentence structures convey the same message, but differs in when the observation was made about his having acquired the experience. But sometimes, this difference is not trivial. For example, in a trial murder.

The prosecutor asks:

> What did you think was the state of his mind on the night of the murder three months ago, Dec 24th?

Defendant replies

> He had hallucination before he was murdered three months ago.

Prosecutor irritatedly responds:

> I am not asking about any hallucination he had on Dec 24th.

Defendant replies again

> He had experience of hallucinating before he was murdered on Dec 24th.

Prosecutor, still annoyed

> I am not asking what your opinion is today of his past-experience prior to Dec 24th. I am asking about what you had observed on 24th Dec. about his past-experience.

Defendant complies

> On that day, 24th Dec, he had {had the experience} hallucinating since childhood.
>   On 24th Dec, he had experienced hallucinations since childhood.
>   On 24th Dec, he had had hallucinations since childhood.

**Cascaded temporal projections**
The perfection of participation can get more complex with a cascaded temporal projection ...

Prosecutor asks again,

> Then what about what you had remembered on 24th Dec, about an incident on 20th Dec?

Defendant responds with precision
(temporal displacement of defendant's observation to 24th Dec,
but temporal displacement of deceased's status to 20th Dec):

> On Dec 24th, I had wanted to teach him because, I had believed that the deceased had

```
{  
  never had {experienced satisfactory sex}  
  by the time of his birthday on 20th Dec
}.
```

Which can be translated to,

> On Dec 24th, I had wanted to teach him because, I had believed that the deceased had

```
{  
  had {experienced unsatisfactory sex}  
  by the time of his birthday on 20th Dec
}.
```

Which can be translated to,

> On Dec 24th, I had wanted to teach him because, I had believed that the deceased had

```
{  
  never had {had satisfactory sex}  
  by the time of his birthday on 20th Dec
}.
```

Which can be translated to,

> On Dec 24th, I had wanted to teach him because, I had believed that the deceased had

```
{  
  had {had unsatisfactory sex}  
  by the time of his birthday on 20th Dec
}.
```

**Using your original sentences as example**
Temporal displacement to present:

> I had my car for four years before I ever learned to drive it today.

Temporal displacement to last year:

> I had had my car for four years before I had ever learned to drive it last year.

Comment: Thank you for going into as much detail as you did. Enjoyed reading it through.