# Past Perfect and Past tense

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

I'm having difficulty understanding when to use Past tense and past perfect together. For example:

1. I had to do that pose because there were no other poses to do.
2. I did that pose because there were no other poses to do.

Which one is correct? Because of my understanding Past perfect is something that happened before past tense. Example: when i entered the room, she had already left. Which means she had already left before i etered the room. 
But in the number 1 sentence it feels so right... I don't know. Please help

Comment: That's not a perfect in #1 -- it's the 'periphrastic modal' *have to* = *must*. "I was obliged to do that pose ...".

Comment: hm.. why can't we use Had to???

Comment: @StoneyB I feel a sudden urge to call a pub or a rock group 'The Periphrastic Modal/s'.

Comment: StoneyB is saying your analysis is wrong, not your example.

Comment: i have no idea what you guys are talking about... please be more specific.. thanks..

Comment: They are saying that your first example is not the past perfect. The past perfect would be, "I had done that pose..."

Comment: but i thought "had" is past perfect?

Comment: You're correct, that's what I meant to type; edited.

Comment: 1. present tense: *I have to do that pose* ( i.e. I must pose)  2. past simple: *I had to do that pose* 3. past perfect: *I had had to do that pose*

Comment: So sentence #1 is just Past tense? not past perfect? Because if it were past perfect it would be "I had had to do that pose... OR I had done that pose...." Am i correct?

Comment: [What does “had had” mean? How does this differ from “had”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2658/what-does-had-had-mean-how-does-this-differ-from-had) and [When do we use “had had” and “have had”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108299/when-do-we-use-had-had-and-have-had) Both your examples use the simple past tense.

Answer (score 3):

The perfect construction uses *have*, but always with the past participle of the following verb.

> When I entered she had already **left** the room.
>   I have **done** that pose many times.

In your sentence #1, however, *have* is not used with a past participle but with a 'marked' infinitive (marked, that is, with *to*):

> I had **to do** that pose ...

This construction is not a perfect but a 'periphrastic modal'—that is, an expression which 'paraphrases' a modal verb (*can/could, may/might, must, shall/should, will/would*) and has the same meaning. *HAVE to VERB* means the same thing as *must VERB*; but *HAVE to* is much more flexible than *must* because it *HAVE* has all the forms of an ordinary verb, where *must* has only one form.

> I **must** do that pose.

*HAVE to* in your sentence #1 is cast in the preterite tense, *had to*, and has past reference. It can also be cast in the non-past tense, with present or future reference:

> PRETERITE: I **had to** do that pose ...
>   NON-PAST: I **have to** do that pose ...

It has an infinitive form which can combine with the modal *will* for future reference, or head an infinitival clause:

> MODAL FUTURE: I will **have to** do that pose ...
>   INFINITIVAL: I hoped not **to have to** do that pose any more.

It can be cast as a past participle and employed in a present, past or future perfect construction:

> PRESENT PERFECT: I have **had to** do that pose ...
>   PAST PERFECT: I had **had to** do that pose ...

It also has a gerund-participle form, which can be employed adjectivally or in a progressive construction or a gerund clause:

> ADJECTIVAL PARTICPLE: Anybody **having to** do that pose thinks about quitting.
>   PROGRESSIVE: These days I'm **having to** do that pose at every session.
>   GERUND CLAUSE: **Having to** do that pose was tedious.