# `had had finished` - is that correct?

Tags: tenses, past-perfect

Someone's told me today that

> I had had already finished

is grammatically correct and it means:

> In the past, I had already finished.

Is this grammatically correct? I feel like past perfect is enough and I've never seen two *had* followed by yet another verb.

Comment: Someone misled you. Lots of guidance on *had had* at: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108299/when-do-we-use-had-had-and-have-had

Comment: In case you wanted to have some fun with your friend: [James while John had had had had had had had had had had had a better effect on the teacher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_while_John_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_a_better_effect_on_the_teacher). (Not an answer to your question, though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I had had already finished" is not correct.  "I had already finished" is what you mean.  However you can say "I had had", as in for example "by midnight I had had enough to eat."  You are telling someone about an action which was complete at some time in the past.