# Why can I write the same word twice in a row and still be grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

A sentence such as "I'd had an ice cream" is correct, and but when there is no apostrophe it becomes "I had had an ice cream"... Is this ok to write?

Comment: Yes, it's grammatical. It's the same as saying *I **had eaten** an ice-cream*

Comment: "had had" is the past perfect (pluperfect) of "have". Just as you can say "I had spoken", you can say "I had had".

Comment: I should have cast my vote to close this question as a duplicate of [What does “had had” mean? How does this differ from “had”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2658/what-does-had-had-mean-how-does-this-differ-from-had) Someone else can.

Comment: Yes, you can. Consecutive, identically-spelt words isn’t automatically ungrammatical. Just wait till you encounter the buffalo.